# How to create dynamic reusable functional component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, react-component

I want to create a dynamic reusable component. I know that it can be done with the help of props something like that:

```
const Sidebar = (props)=>{
return(
<div className="sidebar">
<ul>
<li>{props.list1}</li>
<li>{props.list1}</li>
<li>{props.list1}</li>
<li>{props.list1}</li>
...
</ul>
</div>
)
}
```

Here there is a **problem**. I do not know how many `<li>` are going to come in the sidebar. In some cases sidebar can be large or small.
When I create the dynamic component with the above approach (with the help of `props`), then  I must have a fixed number of list items.
How can I be able to create a reusable component with the dynamic data as well as the dynamic number of `<li>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` to iterate over the array and render it as a list.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```js
const Sidebar = (props)=>{

const sidebarItems = props.list1.map(i => <li>{i}</li>);


return(
<div className="sidebar">
<ul>
 {sidebarItems}
</ul>
</div>
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar list1={["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]}/>, document.getElementById('sidebar'));

ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar list1={["onlyOne"]}/>, document.getElementById('smaller'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="sidebar"></div>

<div id="smaller"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I always appriciate upvotes on my answers :)

Comment: But I have a different scenario. I have a JavaScript object, that I pass as `prop`  to a sidebar component and inside the object, there is an array of lists. I am facing a problem while iterating through the array which is inside the object.

Comment: if you are passing an object as a prop, you can get the array by it's key, for example `myList = props.theObject.list1;`

Comment: Amazing! I did it!  Thank you for your explanation. The community over the internet is really amazing.  Thank you alot. :) Love from **Pakistan**.

Comment: Thanks, Mehdi! I always appreciate upvotes on answers as well ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239190/discussion-between-joshua-craven-and-mehdi-saqlen).

Comment: and he never thanked with an upvote xD @JoshuaCraven just upvoted, well deserved